# How i can Insert contents of text file with heredoc and variable with ruby

Tags: ruby, string, file, heredoc

There was a problem when im creating the CLI. I'm want to give the user the opportunity to insert their data into a text file, for this I created a file and added a heredoc to it
I'm trying to get data from a text document that has a heredoc inside of it with a function that is supposed to interpolate
When I try to display the result of the file, I get the entire contents of the file, including the heredoc

an example will be below

I tried to solve my problem through File class

```rb
variable_name = File::open("path_directory/file_with_heredoc.txt", "r+")::read
```

Next, I decided to give the value of the variable to the terminal via

```rb
exec("echo #{variable_name}")
```

The terminal displays

```rb
file = <<-EOM
  single text with def result: #{upcase_def("Hello")}
EOM
```

Tried to give through struct, but result is unchanged

```rb
exec("echo #{variable_name.strip}")
```

What do I need to do to get only data, no HEREDOC syntax?
I want to get this result

```rb
"single text with def result: HELLO"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you actually try to achieve? Will you need to read man different files? With different variable names? Where are those files coming from? Can you trust them, or is it possible that those files contain malicious code?

Comment: I'm doing a small pet project using the gli gem
There will be as many files as the user decides to create, but only one file can be called
I create files through the open File::open("./doc/#{fileName}.txt", "w+") do /f/
f.rwrite("file = <<-EOM
  single text with def result: #{upcase_def("Hello")}
EOM)

Comment: I do not understand why you need the variable name and the heredoc in the file, especially since it has a `.txt` file extension and not `.rb`? Why can't users simply inset pure text into that file, and you assign it to a variable in your code after loading the txt file? That would be easier for the users, because they do not have to care about Ruby syntax. And it would be more secure, because you will not need to evaluate code from an untrusted source (the user).

Comment: Okay, I'll take your advice and remove the heredoc from the document.
This is my first project, I'm just getting acquainted with the principles of development/system design, so I can make mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do but I recommend you to first do some research why '**eval() is evil**'. If the file is a user (or hacker) input you definitely want some sanitization there or a completely different approach.

```rb
def upcase_def(str)
  str.upcase
end

data = File.read('file_with_heredoc.txt')
eval(data)
# => "  single text with def result: HELLO\n"
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the OP described in the first paragraph of the question that users will change the content of the file in question. That means users would be able to change the content to anything and as long as it is valid Ruby code that code would be evaluated. That means users would be able to steal secrets or delete files and data with this approach if they want to...

Comment: I posted this only because OP already calls `exec()` and tried to discourage them from using my solution. There already was your comment on the question saying "don't do it" and I added mine "this can be done, don't do it".

If OP asked something like "How can I parse a user input with placeholders", the answer would be completely different.

Comment: @spickermann You can use `%p` or #inspect to make eval safer. For example: `eval("%p" % "foo = 'bar'")` will just return a String rather than implement an assignment. While there are often better ways to solve things than Kernel#eval, especally for the OP's use case, I find the knee-jerk refrain of "Never use eval!" in Ruby and Bash threads tiring. If there were zero valid uses for using eval, the construct would be removed from the language. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

### Use File Methods to Read Text Files

A here-doc is really intended to inline long String objects directly into your code. Using it as storage for an external file or the contents of a CLI string argument is like using a saw to pound in a nail. Don't do that.

If you really want to store a here-doc in an external file, you should source that file (e.g. by using [Kernel#load](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-load)) rather than trying to parse it. In your case, this is still a bad idea because:

1. You should *never* trust unsanitized user input.
2. The sourced file could contain any Ruby code at all, which makes it at least as bad as [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) when called on untrusted data.
3. If the external file is yours anyway, and you trust its contents, there are much easier ways to do this.

The easiest thing to do is simply read in the text file, either as a single String or as an Array of lines. You do this with File#read or File#readlines; these methods are inherited from the [IO](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/IO.html) module, which is subclassed by [File](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/File.html). For example:

```rb
# we'll assume the filename to read is the
# first argument to your script; otherwise
# just assign a filename as a String
text_file = ARGV[0]
 
# @return [String] all lines as a single
#   object stored in +str+
str = File.read text_file

# @return [Array<String>] array of lines
#   stored in +arr+
arr = File.readlines text_file
```

### See Also

- [IO#read](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/IO.html#method-c-read)
- [IO#readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines)